# Trying to get an image overlay and image zoom to appear at same time on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, image, transition

I'm having difficulty trying to get an image overlay and image zoom to appear at the same time on mouse hover. For some reason, the overlay disappears when I added the image zoom. It seems like one webkit transition cancels the other out. Either the zoom will work or the overlay will appear but not both. Any help is greatly appreciated, I've been researching for hours and can't seem to figure it out.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="image_wrap">
    <div class="caption">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <p class="heading">
            Resort Website
        </p>
    </div>
    <img src="css/images/resort.jpg" alt="resort" class="portfolio-pic">
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
 .image_wrap{
   position:relative;
 }

.image_wrap .caption{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align:center   
  display:inline-block;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(51, 153, 170, 0.9), rgba(51, 153, 170, 0.8));
  -webkit-transition:all .4s ease-in-out;
  transition:all .4s ease-in-out
}

.image_wrap .caption:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}

.image_wrap .caption img {
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition:all .4s linear;
  transition:all .4s linear;
}

.image_wrap .caption:hover img {
  -ms-transform:scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
  transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

Comment: what is your expected output.

Comment: Output is to have the image zoom in and overlay appear at the same time, just like this example: http://www.cssscript.com/demo/animated-image-hover-overlay-with-image-scale/

Comment: try this [hover](https://fiddle.jshell.net/bhsrn8cn/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped!! I just added overflow:hidden to .image_wrap{position:relative;) and it came out perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I detect two problems on your code, change this:

```
.image_wrap .caption:hover img {
-ms-transform:scale(1.2);
-webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
transform:scale(1.2);
}
```

For this:

```
.image_wrap:hover img {
   -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
   transform: scale(1.2);
   z-index:8;
 }
```

You can answer why. Because your image not inside .caption and you didn't declare the z-index (caption on the image).

Declare the z-index on caption too.

```
.image_wrap:hover .caption {
   opacity: 1;
   z-index:9999;
 }
```

Here is the link for jsfiddle where I test our code: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2mnu3atu/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and input!  This helped me gain an understanding on declaring the  z-index. Thanks again.